# Pair class getPair method

Tags: java, class, this, getter

I'm trying to make a class that acts as a pair of ints. I want to make a getter method which returns a pair, but I'm hesitant to write as it looks weird and I want to know if it legal to do this in Java or not.

The code is here:

```
public class Pair
{
    private int p1;
    private int p2;

    public Pair (int p1, int p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public Pair getPair () {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And is this a good way to return the pair, or is there an optimal way to do so?

Comment: Ummm... well there's nothing specifically *wrong* with doing that, so it is legal Java. But it seems quite useless. Why do you need it?

Comment: Why return a reference to an object that you already have?

Comment: Try to write the code that would use a Pair and you should understand that the getter you wrote is not very useful as you already have a Pair...

Comment: I though that when I use the getPair it returns the pair object which will then get the ints, but as most of the other answers suggest, its best to create a getter for each int

Thanks everybody for ur help

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can only call `getPair()` *on* a pair, why would you want this? Surely you would have a method to return a pair *on some other type*, e.g.

```
Pair getCoordinates() {
    ...
}
```

Note that your *name* is very general (a pair of what? Oh, a pair of integers...) which suggests that perhaps it should be a generic type - although you then end up with boxing for the integer case you're interested in.

While in the past I'd have supported a class like this, I've been finding more recently that a private nested type with just a bunch of fields can actually be more useful, to simply transport a collection of disparate values within a particular class.

Answer (score 1):

The method `getPair()` is redundant: When you create a new `Pair` you will already have a reference to it; e.g.

```
Pair p1 = new Pair(3,5);
Pair p2 = p1.getPair();
assert p1 == p2; // p1 and p2 refer to the same object.
```

Hence `getPair()` is of no use.  Note that one legitimate use for a method to return `this` is when implementing the builder pattern, as it allows for more compact code; e.g.

```
Foo foo = new FooBuilder().setA(1).setB("bar").setC(99.9).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not normal at all, to return a reference to `this` from a getter. Seeing as if you are calling `getPair()` you ***already*** have a reference to it. Now, if what you are trying to do is create a factory method for getting new instances of Pair, then you might want to try something like this:

```
public class Pair
{
    public static Pair createPair(int p1, int p2) {
        return new Pair(p1, p2);
    }

    private int p1;
    private int p2;

    public Pair (int p1, int p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
}
```

But even this is a trivial addition, since it provides practically no benefit over just using the constructor to create new `Pair` instances.

Answer (score 0):

What you've got already won't make your `Pair` class any more usable - if you have a reference to a `Pair` object then you don't need another!

It's perfectly ok to have two separate accessors:

```
public int getFirstInt() {
    return this.p1;
}

public int getSecondInt() {
   return this.p2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement 2 getter methods.

```
public int getP1() {
    return this.p1;
}

public int getP2() {
    return this.p2;
}
```